# how to make something display on a certain point on a website

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a 'scroll back to top' arrow on my website just like they have on this website:

http://www.tonischildersbedrijf.nl

But they make it display on a certain point on the website (halfway). What js are they using for this?

Comment: see the `CSS` for `position: fixed` and `position: absolute` in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Why not use the Developer Tools in your browser and find out?

Comment: So you want to display the Arrow when the user scrolls down?  window.scrollY != 0?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css or jquery or google to find out what to use. Heres a tutorial I found after a quick google. Its a good idea to do a bit of reseach before asking questions on here.

http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-an-animated-scroll-to-top-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep track of the scrolling using [window.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll). In that method you can check the window.scrollY property.  If the property is 0, that means user is in top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website that you put down as a reference and here is your answer. This is done with JS or in the HTML. In the website you provided it was HTML that they used. It is done by selecting an element ID within the page to scroll to by `<a href=>`. For example, you may have at the bottom of the page

```
<a href="#top">Home</a>
```

and this would send you back to the element ID "top" and in this case, it would be the top of the page. If you post your code I can modify it for you so that you can achieve this with just HTML.